# Atmosphere Framework Disconnect

Tags: javascript, grails, web, websocket, atmosphere

I am currently facing an issue using the Atmosphere Framework grails plugin, which is basically the Java and Javascript implementation of Atmosphere, but my question is specifically dealing with the JS (https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript)

I am hitting a roadblock currently when a disconnect happens, and while it is more of a problem on mobile browsers, desktop browsers have issues sometimes as well. We get a "broken frame" error, which states:

```
WebSocket connection to '{URL}' failed: Received a broken close frame containing a reserved status code.
```

This occurs whenever internet is interrupted for any reason on any device. Wifi, 3g/4g, whatever. The only browser that seems to somewhat handle this is Firefox, and even that is touch and go. We currently have a hackjob in to try to reconnect clients to the socket, and it works fairly decently on desktops, but not very well on mobile. The library states this functionality should be built in, but it doesn't seem to be functional and I cannot find much online that talks about reconnecting to a socket that was closed due to a connection interuption.

So, finally my question. I want to know how others that use this framework handle internet interruptions on browsers, specifically Chrome, Safari, and IE. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which plugin are you using, [atmosphere](https://grails.org/plugins/atmosphere) or [atmosphere-meteor](https://grails.org/plugins/atmosphere-meteor)? I'm the author of atmosphere-meteor, and I'll try and help you with it.

Comment: We are using Atmosphere Meteor with the JS/Java from jfarcand's code.

We have managed to fix a number of issues so far, but are having issues with getting sockets to not instantly die out when a cell phone loses wifi connection and swaps to 3g/4g then back to wifi.

Comment: We are currently in a state where every 2nd reconnect leaves us with a socket that recieves heartbeats but doesn't actually ferry messages. (We suspect the previous socket is getting assigned right before it's closed, and the client is left thinking it's connected but isn't).

Comment: I suggest asking your question at the [Atmosphere Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/atmosphere-framework) since it's probably related to the framework and not the plugin. I'm a hobby developer, and I haven't done much mobile testing. Could it be a problem with the underlying HttpSession? Does the phone keep the same JSESSIONID across the network changes?
You mentioned that you’ve had to work around several problems. I’m looking for ways to improve the plugin, so please [create an issue]( https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-atmosphere-meteor/issues) with your suggestions.

Comment: You can also create one or more [wiki pages]( https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-atmosphere-meteor/wiki) with your lessons learned. I’ll add links to the README the next time I update the plugin.

Comment: Our scenario is kind of odd as we have the most up to date version of the JS currently, but the server cannot be updated yet because reasons. It looks like an issue with the Broadcaster in the version we are using, we have a work around now that suffices (Destroy (if exists) and create a new broadcaster for each new connection) until we can update the server and fix this proper. I will keep that Atmosphere Group in mind for the future though, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to post a copy of that comment below so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added my comments to the answer, but you should check [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&nomobile=true#!topic/atmosphere-framework/EIn8jdKZpAs). It seems related to your problem.

I suggest asking your question at the Atmosphere Group since it's probably related to the framework and not the plugin. I'm a hobby developer, and I haven't done much mobile testing. Could it be a problem with the underlying HttpSession? Does the phone keep the same JSESSIONID across the network changes? You mentioned that you’ve had to work around several problems. I’m looking for ways to improve the plugin, so please [create an issue](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-atmosphere-meteor/issues) with your suggestions.

You can also create one or more [wiki pages](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-atmosphere-meteor/wiki) with your lessons learned. I’ll add links to the README the next time I update the plugin.

Comment: I just now got put in charge of upgrading our project from 0.7.0 to 1.0.3 and I just wanted to drop by really quick and thank you for your documentation. Getting compatible with the plugin (not the framework, the plugin) has been a breeze and took me minutes. Keep up the great work. Especially noting how to get the configuration when you changed the contextHolder.